# Is there a better place for the IF statement in the for loop

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

```
For k = 0 To (.Cells(38, 4).Value - 1)
    For i = 70 To 73
        For j = 0 To 2
            If j = 0 Then
                bumpvalue = k * (.Cells(39, 4).Value + .Cells(31, 4).Value)
            Else
                bumpvalue = 0
            End If
            StartPoint(j) = .Cells(i, 8 + j).Value + bumpvalue
            EndPoint(j) = .Cells(i + 1, 8 + j).Value + bumpvalue
        Next j

        Set lineObj = DWGFile.ModelSpace.AddLine(StartPoint, EndPoint)
    Next i
Next k
```

Is there a better place or way to implement the "bumpvalue" which only applies when j = 0?

something tells me below does not fly.

```
 StartPoint(j) = .Cells(i, 8 + j).Value + if j = 0 then k * (.Cells(39, 4).Value + .Cells(31, 4).Value) else 0
```

Comment: The code is easily readable now. I would not favor any change (such as is suggested) which would make it less readable.

Comment: @theMayer I was wondering about that.  Their is something definitely to be said about readability and maintenance.  And in my case performance really is not an issue.  Just something inside me wants to know if there is a better way since I am slowly teaching myself VBA.  I am glad I asked the question so far as I never knew about IIF.  Works just like the IF function in Excel.

Comment: The performance hit of a single if-statement evaluating inequality to zero every time after the first is almost the same as though there were no if statement due to branch prediction.

Comment: But you never should write code for the compiler. Write code for the humans, the poor souls who have to maintain it after you’re gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea was very close.  Try the `IIf` statement instead:

```
StartPoint(j) = .Cells(i, 8 + j).Value + IIf(j = 0, k * (.Cells(39, 4).Value + .Cells(31, 4).Value), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you I have not heard of IIF.  I will have to read up on that one.  Thank you.